# Ros on android device?

Tags: ros, android-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i'm developping and android app to control a security robot runing with Ros, the question is do i need to install ROS on my Mobile device to make sure the interaction with the Robot.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130901/ros-on-android-device-?/) by [shiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/12161/shiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would advise you to take a look at http://wiki.ros.org/android

---

Originally posted by [mathijsdelangen](https://answers.ros.org/users/11976/mathijsdelangen/) with karma: 88 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1